# A game of groups...

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that a dealer possesses a finite group $G$ of order $n$ with its elements enumerated $g_{1}, g_{2}, \dots, g_{n}$ and presents you with an empty Cayley table and informs you of the order of the group and that $g_{1}$ is the identity element.

He then ''deals'' you $k$ entries of the Cayley table (something resembling the example below) and you win if you can fill out the entire table. Is it known whether there exists some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $k \geq m$, then you can win the game for the particular game on $G$ or, conversely, if $k \leq m$ then you are guaranteed to lose on $G$? So, for an easy example, if you are dealt the following:

$$
    \begin{array}{c|c c c c c}
      & g_{1} & g_{2} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} \\
\hline
g_{1} & g_{1} & & & & \\
g_{2} & & g_{3} & & & g_{1}\\ 
g_{3} & & g_{4} & g_{5} &g_{1} &\\
g_{4} & & g_{5}& &g_{2} &g_{3} \\
g_{5} & & & & &\\
    \end{array}
$$
then you can win the game (in fact this is one of the first exercises about groups in Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*).

Moreover, what if the dealer doesn't inform you of the identity element? (Note: I posted a similar question yesterday, but it was posed very poorly and I ended up deleting it.)

Comment: This is a group of order $\;5\;$ so there are *no* elements of order two...and you already know what the identity is. All the other elements have order five. How far can you get with this?

Comment: just knowing the order is $5$ is enough.

Comment: The answer will largely depend on what value the order is... in the given example $n$ was $5$ which was prime, so we already know what the group structure is like, we just needed to figure out what label to assign each element.  Indeed, whenever $n$ is prime, this will be a relatively simple task.  Once there are multiple possible group structures for groups of that order, you will run into more difficulty.  For $\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_2$, you can be told the entire half of the table corresponding to $\langle (1,0)\rangle$ and not have a clue as to how to assign labels for the rest.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a different letter for $n$? Because $n$ is the order of the group.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am not sure what you are asking. How *far* I can get is that I can fill out the Cayley table which is the point of the game. Obviously this is an easy example, but I am asking about in general.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Not quite: e.g. you need to know which permutation of $[ g_3, g_4, g_5]$ is $[g_2^2, g_2^3, g_2^4]$.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Yes I understand that for the example, it is quite easy. But I am asking in general. And I changed the $n$ to $m$ for the bound question.

Comment: @Oiler In general it may impossible depending on what elements and their position, or any other relevant information, is given.

Comment: Do you want to recover the table the dealer has hidden, or do you just want to complete the table so that it is a group (even if not the same table as the dealer's)?

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't believe that. For instance, if the dealer deals $n^2 - 1$ entries, then you can certainly win. However, this seems like it would be overkill...

Comment: @verret Good question... I had in mind that you would have to obtain the Cayley table for the group possessed by the dealer. Is it possible to obtain a Cayley table for a different group of equal order? Do you possibly have an example?

Comment: @Oiler, Yes, of course. Suppose the group has order 4 and the dealer gives you no entry except the identity. You can fill it up as the Klein group, or you can fill it up as a cyclic group of order $4$. (In the last case, you can even do this in three different ways, depending which element you choose to have order $2$.)